# How to disable auto hot reload on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-test

I have search for this issue and seen solutions, but I am not able to figure out the issue.
i get some error because every time write the code, its directly run hot reloads before i finish complete the code. so, how to disable automatic hot reloads in flutter?
automatic hot reloads in flutter is so annoying, i just want to use hot reloads base on Ctrl + S. how i do that?
i'am using visual studio code by the way.

Comment: you might no longer need to disable this manually. see [Flutter hot reload doesn't work on autosave in VSCode](/q/65975713/11107541)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disable auto save on VsCode:

Go to **File > Preferences > settings**

Choose off from the auto save drop down.

Comment: if i disable flutter hot reload on save, i can't use Ctrl+S to reload by my self

Comment: Don't disable hot reload, it's quite handy. Just disable auto save and ise ctr + s everytime.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Android Studio 4.1 go to:

On Mac: Android Studio -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter

On Windows: File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter

---

Then, after being at Flutter section, look for "App Execution" and there you have to uncheck the box "Perform hot reload on save". Then click OK and that's it.

Here is how:

[image: Image that shows the process]

Answer (score 6):

In VS Code, alternative to turning off auto-save:

Turn off these settings:

**Settings** > **Extensions** > **Dart & Flutter** > **Flutter Hot Reload On Save**

**Settings** > **Extensions** > **Dart & Flutter** > **Flutter Hot Restart On Save**

[image: Dart flutter settings: hot reload/restart on save]

Then use **Run** > **Restart Debugging** to restart manually or **Crtl + F5** to Hot Reload

[image: hot reload duebugging bar]

Answer (score 2):

1. To disable **Auto Save** on VS Code

   Go to **File > Preferences > settings** turn off Auto Save

[image]

2. To disable **Hot Reload or Hot Restart on save** search setting with auto hot, and disable the setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intellij IDEA (or Android Studio) you might as well disable Hot UI if enabled:

**File > Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter > Enable Hot UI (disable it)**

Comment: if i disable flutter hot reload on save, i can't use Ctrl+S to reload by my self

Comment: The question is about hot reload, not hot UI.