# Visual Studio Code auto hot reload file changes

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

i'm currently using Visual Studio code and Flutter, when i type every thing in editor without saving changes, vsCode reloaded my application which i run it on emulator, i want to disable this feature and enabling `CTRL+S` to reload,

i can't find how can i do that? thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61233597/11107541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am curious if that is because of auto save setting in Visual Studio Code:

[image: VSCode preferences]

Comment: Good catch - I've filed an issue to support this: https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3033